# How can I put the output into one line?

Tags: python-3.x

I wanna put the output into one line like:

```
It is not a prime number. 
It's common divisors are: 1,2,7,14.
```

instead of

```
It is not a prime number. 
It's common divisors are: 
1,2,7,14.
```

I am a beginner of python.

[image: picture1]

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the first `print` function to print everything as one string instead of using the `print` function twice.

For instance, you could do :

```
divisors = [1, 2, 7, 14]

divisors_as_string = [str(d) for d in divisors]
print(divisors_as_string)
# > ["1", "2", "7", "14"]

# use the join method to join all strings in your divisors_as_string list
# note that they will be separated by ", " as is specified before in the join method
print("It is not a prime number. It's common divisors are:"+", ".join(divisors_as_string)+".")
# > It is not a prime number. It's common divisors are: 1, 2, 7, 14.
```

Feel free to ask for any further help, and don't forget to mark the question as answered if you solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I would say you have two simple options here:

- Doing every calculation and then printing everything with one print()
- Using this python3 functionality:

print("test", end = '')

```
print("Hello ", end = '')
print("world!")
# Output should be: Hello world!
```